# Get counts row wise and add result as new column

Tags: r

I have this R data frame:

```
v1 <- LETTERS[1:10]
v2 <- LETTERS[1:4]
v3 <- LETTERS[4:5]
dat <- data.frame(cbind(v1,v2,v3))

v1 v2 v3
A  A  D
B  B  E
C  C  D
D  D  E
E  A  D
F  B  E
G  C  D
H  D  E
I  A  D
J  B  E
```

I would like to get a count of the number of occurrences of a given value (e.g. "A") for each column, 
and save that as a new column in my data frame. 
I my dataframe I want to calculate the occurrences af "A" in column v1 thru v3, and make a new column (CountA) with the count of A's.

My desired output would be:

```
v1 v2 v3  CountA
A  A  D   2
B  B  E   0
C  C  D   0
D  D  E   0
E  A  D   1
F  B  E   0
G  C  D   0
H  D  E   0
I  A  D   1
J  B  E   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dat$CountA <- rowSums(dat=="A")
```